# Sql string search

Tags: sql, string, search, select

**This is my question:**

*Find the capital and the name where the capital includes the name of the country.*

**This is my answer:**

```
SELECT name,capital
FROM world WHERE 
capital=concat(name,"NULL")
```

I dont understand what should i do in the "WHERE" part.

Should i do **capital=concat(name,something?)** or **IN** or **LIKE?**

Can you help me please? Thank you.

*The question is from this link:
http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_names
Question 13*

Comment: It mostly depends of how you need to order your result. If you want to order by relevance, then full text search is needed, else, LIKE will do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do with the `NULL` there, but basically you if you want to find a capital that contains the name of the country, the usage of the `like` operator is definitely in order. Just slap a couple of wildcards (`%`) around it, and you should be good to go:

```
SELECT name, capital
FROM   world
WHERE  capital LIKE CONCAT('%', name, '%')
```

Answer (score 1):

`CONCAT` is not necessary here, you should be able to use:

```
  WHERE [capital] LIKE '%[name]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simething like:

```
SELECT name,capital
FROM world
WHERE capital like '%' + name + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is , it's good to keep SELECT, FROM , and WHERE all on separate lines. like so :

```
SELECT ....

FROM ...

WHERE ...
```

This make it easy to think.

Next , we think about the pieces we will use. We need a `LIKE` , we need something related to `capital` , and `name` , and also - a way to use the name with extra characters - that is the `concat` function:

```
SELECT name,capital
FROM world 
WHERE  capital like concat('%', name ,'%')
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried
Select name, capital From world where capital like concat ('%', name, '%')

Comment: not exactly. for example when capital is mexico city and name is mexico, it doesnt work.

Comment: @user3027665 ok I thought you were talking about problem 11. In this case try Select name, capital From world where capital like concat ('%', name, '%')

Answer (score -1):

this is the correct answer:

```
SELECT name,capital
FROM world
WHERE capital 
LIKE concat(concat('%',name),'%')
```